# message queue. msgsend msgrcv. System V IPC system calls in C (Linux)

Tags: c, synchronization, shared-memory, msgrcv, msgsend

Hi I'm working with some shared memory where different processes read and write data. I'm using a message queue to store messages of when data has changed between read and write operations.

```
/* struct that defines a message */
struct msgbuf{
  long mtype;         /* must be positive */
  int childId;        //ID of child sending message
  int bufferChanged;  //Buffer at which value was changed
  int beforeValue;    //Value before child sleeps
  int afterValue;     //Value after child sleeps
};
```

So while reading and writing and checking for changes the processes store messages the following way

```
struct msgbuf msg = {BUFFER_CHANGED, id, position, read, bufferArr[position]};
if(msgsnd(msqid, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0)== -1){
  perror("msgsnd in read.write");
}
```

This is working fine. Oh by the way here's how I create the message queue.

```
#define BUFFER_CHANGED 1

qKey = ftok("./", 'A');

msqid = msgget(qKey, (IPC_CREAT | 0666));

/*Perform the following if the call is unsuccessful.*/
if(msqid == -1){
  printf ("\nThe msgget call failed, error number = %d\n", errno);
}
/*Return the msqid upon successful completion.*/
else{
  printf ("\nMessage queue successful. The msqid = %d\n", msqid);
  //exit(0);
}
```

So my problem is that I'm not quite sure how to retrieve messages from the queue and display them on the screen.  I've been reading up on `msgrcv()` system call, but it's not very clear to me.

```
rc = msgrcv(msqid, &msg, sizeof(msg), BUFFER_CHANGED, IPC_NOWAIT);
```

`rc` is an `int` since `msgrcv()` returns an `int`. How do I point this `int` to the actual message? How to I read contents from the message so I can display them? I'm assuming this should be done in some sort of loop.

Answer (score 0):

The return value is an `int` because it's telling you how much data it read into your message buffer - in your case you want to see `4 * sizeof(int)` come back for a full message.  If `rc` comes back as -1, you have an error.  If `rc` came back as a positive number, at least some of the fields of `msg` will have the received message data.

Check out the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
rc = msgrcv(msqid, &msg, sizeof(msg), BUFFER_CHANGED, IPC_NOWAIT)
```

The `msg` contains the data that you want to display on the screen. Since IPC_NOWAIT is used, the function returns immediately without blocking. The rc value will be -1 if no msg was read, else it will be the number of bytes read from the msgq.